# Wing fuselage joint in small aeroplanes

Tags: aircraft-design, wing, aircraft-structures, fuselage

I know that there are bolts to connect the centre wing boxes of the fuselage and wings in large aircraft, but what are the methods of connecting the wings and fuselage of small aeroplanes? I’m mostly curious about spars that go from wingtip to wingtip.

Comment: [(Shortened) video of the wings being removed on a Cessna 152](https://youtu.be/udjp3PUw-VA?t=430). It shows the wing bolt locations.

Comment: @Suryetto, if you think this question is not a duplicate of the linked one, the correct procedure is to answer here in the comments or to edit your question to make the difference more prominent, not flag the automated comments.

Comment: Why would a small GA aircraft be significantly different in construction method than a large commercial passenger liner? Just because it's small doesn't mean they forgo bolts and use superglue instead...

Comment: " I’m mostly curious about spars that go from wingtip to wingtip."  The spars in my Cessna Cardinal do not go from wingtip to wingtip. The wing spars connect to a carrythru spar that runs across the top of the cabin.  Looks like a big aluminum I-beam.  Here's a  shot of one from Cardinalflyers.com https://community.cardinalflyers.com/uploads/db0560/optimized/1X/d5bba206bf5eb9150e24b57978bf648c92724c20_2_999x750.jpeg  You can't see the big studs that are used to attach the wing to the ends of tho.

Comment: The post is NOT a duplicate of the answer which talks about airlines. My airplane is a low wing homebuilt, a PL-2 http://pazmany.com/wp/?cat=15 which has a one-peice wing from tip to tip.The fuselage simply sits on top of the wing and is attached with a bolt at each corner that joins the front and rear spars to the adjacent fuselage frames. This is a structurally superior arrangement insofar as the heavy spar beam root joints are eliminated and is lighter, but you are stuck with a very unwieldy 28 ft long all-of-a-piece wing if you want to take the wing off. So the other method is more common.